# How to find correct place for applying CSS styles in data table

Tags: html, angular, css, typescript

I want through angular-ngStyle to apply some CSS styles in Table data.

Logic is already done: "When table width is less then 1250px, apply some css styles". Here is code for that:

```
export class NanoTableComponent  {

/**
 * This is function which check table width and apply styles if table width is less then 1250px;
 * But problem is to puting this logic on right place in html.
 */
tableStyle(tableWidth: number) {
    console.log('Table Width: ' + tableWidth);
    return tableWidth < 1250 ? { 'min-width':'75px;','flex':'none;' } : { 'flex': '1' };
}
}
```

In the Scss class

```
// ********* HERE IS THE PROBLEM **********
// IF in this thid div I made next change: flex: none; and min-width: 75px; 
// I get what I want. But I want that only if table width is less then 1250px;
// That means I need to add that style dynamically through angular,
// problem is where in html to apply this styles.
> div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 2px;
  > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Here is stackblitz with html, TypeScript and scss files. This does not work but you can saw entire code related with this table:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css24?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnano-table%2F_nano-table.scss

My question is: how to find in html that "div" styles, from scss file, and apply to that div styles dynamically?

My goal is to make this "Name" column bigger to add more width to it:

[image]

Comment: why not use media queries in the scss?

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu cus media queries are related with entire screen not table(div) -width. 
That means screen size is same but table width is different.
IF I have on one page table width 1200px, and on second page table-width 1800px, I can't focus that via media queries.

Comment: you can, if you use different classes on the pages, and target them separately, but I see now what you are looking for and this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu give me some better solution I will very grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your table based on the width

```
<div class="nano-table-row nano-table-grid-header" #table [class.small]="table.offsetWidth< 1250" >
```

And then encapsulate your csscific CSS rules with that class

```
 .small
{
 //specific rules here
}
```

Comment: I tried but that hit "header" of table data, now its smaller: http://i.prntscr.com/f39Fa5E-T7ahnBNDvgnh5w.png

Comment: Can you try fixing your stackblitz example? It's not working at all. And it looks like the width is wider now, isn't it what you wanted

Comment: I will try, and let you know if I succeed.

Comment: I cannot fix this stackblitz. But anyway thanks on tried to help.